# How should I approach my new company regarding lost pay due to late PO approval?

Tags: recruitment, compensation, start-date

I accepted a position through a recruiter to work at a large company. I gave my two week notice to my now ex-employer.

Friday before my agreed upon start date the recruiter calls and says the PO is not signed so you cannot start on Monday. A full week has gone by, I have had numerous email and phone conversations with the recruiter and manager.

They keep telling me I have the job and they are trying to get the PO approved.

Meanwhile I am not getting paid. How should I approach my new company in order to get paid for my lost time working? If I had known it would take this long I would have simply kept working at my previous company.

Comment: Are you asking for legal advice? Your question reads like you are specifically seeking legal advice, which is off topic here. If you are asking how to approach the situation this would be far more on topic - I have edited your question to reflect this, if it changes your intent too much feel free to [edit] to clarify!

Comment: I believe your issue lies with your recruiter, and not the new company.  I am voting to close, though, because you are asking something that has one foot in the "Legal Advice" world, which is prohibited in the Workplace.

Comment: ...also, start looking for another job. It's possible that this one will fall through, and THEN how do you get any money at all? Just keep jobsearching, when you get another offer if recruiter A/company A hasn't moved, contact the recruiter to have them tell company A that it's time to put up or you're moving on. Because while they have a PO to get approved, you have bills to pay. (Also, repeating others' assertions that this sounds like a question for a contract lawyer, and not for general TWP.)

Comment: What do you have in writing and signed by the new employer? Letter of offer? Contract? Anything at all?

Comment: Please edit your question and explain the 'PO' abbreviation. You have an international audience here.

Comment: Did your job offer have a start date, and is it past that? - I might bring that up if so, saying you were expecting to be paid for work you were to be doing on day X, and that the company has been unable to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I approach my new company in order to get paid for my lost
>   time working?

That's pretty crummy. Due to no fault of your own, you aren't able to work when you expected.

While it's doubtful that you have any legal recourse, you can go to your manager and explain that this is a hardship for you. Then ask if there is something the company can do for you.

Unfortunately, if the manager says "There's nothing we can do", you likely have no recourse.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a contract with the new company, let alone a contract with the enforceable penalties clauses that you're looking for. No contract, no clause, no recourse.

You can tell the company your tale of woe, but they have no legal obligation to make you whole.

Here is a definition of [contract](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contract) that is applicable to your situation: "a binding agreement between two or more persons or parties; especially :  one legally enforceable"

Correct me if I am wrong, but you don't have an agreement let alone a binding agreement let alone a binding agreement that's legally enforceable that they are going to make you whole.

Comment: Actually they have a contract as they must have had a formal job offer something either verbally, electronically or vial physical mail. enforcing it might be harder

Comment: @Pepone - It sounds like the recruitor said they have the job not the company, even then, no guarantee it was in writting.

Comment: @Ramhound  in many legal systems a verbal contract Is sill a contract - this is a legal Q